# OnItemClickListener not working for ListView using custom adapter

Tags: android, listview, onitemclicklistener

OnItemClickListener not working for ListView even list is not clickable as well here is my code

```
    pListView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.plist);
    pListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id){

            Log.d("here","in item list click");


        }
    });
```

and xml is below

```
<ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/plist"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:alpha="1" />
```

Comment: The type of view that you are inflating your view as (ListView) is different than the type you are setting as the listener as (AdapterView)

Comment: Your question already has an answer here
[OnItemClickListener not working for ListView using custom adapter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27456326/onitemclicklistener-not-working-in-listview-custom-adapter?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

You doing it wrong so your OnItemCLick method in OnItemClickListener interface is not overrided. Seems like you just typed all this stuff. Android Studio will generate it for you. Just print new OnItem... in .setOnItemClickListener() and let the studio do the magic.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        }
    });
```